# nm symbol size on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, compiler-optimization

We have a large (40Mb) substantially C++ iOS app. Since iOS now requires 32 and 64-bit slices of code, we now have an 86Mb app... This is not useful for trying to get total code+data download under 100Mb.

We suspect there may be large amounts of static data in our app's executable. The man page for Unix nm offers --sort-size and --print-sizes options which should give us what we need. XCode nm doesn't appear to support this.

Is there a script already available to do this re-ordering? (It wouldn't be too hard to write, but seems nonsensical that there is nobody on the web already discussing this!)

Around 50% of our code is also cross-compiled via Unity and IL2CPP, so it's possible we can use .NET introspection tools on the IL for that, but I'd prefer to keep all analysis tied to native size if possible. I am concerned though, that IL2CPP is generating large amounts of C# metadata, which of course since it ends up in the executable then gets encrypted and doesn't compress in the IPA.

Alternatively, has anyone used any other process for iOS *executable* size reduction?

Comment: Have you found an nm --print-size equivalent for macos?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `otool` instead of nm to get the size information you want, although I'm not certain. There is a brief [build size analysis guide](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp-build-size-improvements.322079/) on the Unity forums that might be helpful.

You are correct that a significant portion of the executable is C# metadata. However, we are working now to remove the metadata from the executable, and instead store it in an external file. The latest Unity patch releases have most of the metadata externalized now, and within a few weeks it should all be external. You should be able to find the metadata files in the Data/Managed/Metadata directory in the iOS build output directory.